# select the letters after - in a string

Tags: java, regex

In a java string I have a variable made up of letters separated by hyphen as shown

String task= "schedules-mydailytask"

here is what I have done

```
String [] data=task.split("");
        for(String s:data)
            System.out.println(s);
```

Please how can I use regex to select the letters after -. In this case **mydailytask**

Comment: why use regex? just split around the "-" char and select the index you need

Comment: ok sir will show data

Comment: Can your input have more than one hyphen? If so, what is the expected output?

Comment: please why was I downvoted

Comment: @emsimpson92 only one hyphen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small change in your code `split("-")` split based on `-`

```
String [] data=task.split("-");
    for(String s:data)
        System.out.println(s);
```

or you can just use `String.substring()` and for regex you can follow Tim answer

```
System.out.println(task.substring(task.lastIndexOf("-") + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "schedules-mydailytask";
String[ ] output = input.split("-");
```

Check if output length is greater than 1  then  output[1] is answer.

Answer (score 1):

`String#replaceAll` is the simplest option which pops into my head:

```
String input = "schedules-mydailytask";
String output = input.replaceAll("^.*-", "");
```

### Demo

Comment: The question isn't very clear. What if their input is "this-is-my-input"?

Comment: @emsimpson92 You're right, but it sounds to me as if there is only one hyphen.